# htaccess rewrite removing php error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I'm trying to have mod_rewrite remove the .php at the end of the url.
I am using WAMP
I am using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Which I found here, but when I try to visit the file, I get a

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /uguu/C:/wamp/www/uguu/editor.php on this server.
```

error.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`  with `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
```

Or may be better if your rule looked like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @FrickenHamster `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is an inferred file-mapped path of the request, that's why it includes all the stuff from the filesystem

Comment: The second one failed with

The requested URL /uguu/editor was not found on this server.

Comment: @FrickenHamster is the htaccess file not in the document root? If not then you'll need to replace the `$1` in the condition and rule with `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: I see,
How would I add on to this so that all requests made to uguu/api/..
get sent to api.php?

Thanks

Comment: @FrickenHamster well, you can just turn on multiviews to do that, by adding `Options +Multiviews` and not bother with mod rewrite at all

Comment: Hmm, am I supposed to add
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/uguu/">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews
</Directory>
to the httpd.conf?
It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Add it to the htaccess file